# Prove that $e^{-x^2}<\frac{1}{x^3}$, if $x>0$

Tags: real-analysis, inequality, exponential-function

I have to prove that if $x>0$ then $e^{-x^2}<\frac{1}{x^3}$.
I have thought to set $g(x):=e^{-x^2}-\frac{1}{x^3}$ and from this $g'(x)=-2xe^{-x^2}+\frac{3}{x^4}$, but I think this idea is not good since now I can't prove easily that $g'(x)<0$. Can you help me?

Comment: $e^{-x^2}$ is $\frac1{e^{x^2}}$, so this is basically $\frac1{e^{x^2}}\gt\frac1{x^3}\implies x^3\gt e^{x^2}$ 

Comment: yes I know but proving that inequality is still hard for me...

Comment: It is more convenient to analyze $x^3e^{-x^2}-1.$ Then it is pretty easy to determine that the maximum is attained at $(3/2)^{1/2}.$

Comment: @TheMather-orratherAMather You mean $x^3 < e^{x^2}$?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use that $e^x \geq 1 + x$ for all $x \in \mathbb R$. Then $$e^{x^2/3} \geq 1 + \frac{x^2}3 > x$$ for all $x\in \mathbb R$. Now raise both sides to the third power to get $$e^{x^2} > x^3$$ for all $x \in \mathbb R$.

Comment: Very nice! $e^u \ge 1+u$ was one of my initial thoughts, but I had not seen this.

Comment: Nice indeed! (+)

Comment: In fact, modifying your approach, we have $ e^{x^2/8} \geq 1 + x^2/8 > 2^{1/8} x^{3/8}$ and thus $e^{x^2} > 2x^3$.

Comment: @WimC Your answer has been very useful for me! Only one doubt: with your approach could I prove that $e^{-x^{\alpha}}<\frac{1}{x^{2}}$ $\forall$ $\alpha>0$ and so $\int_0^{\infty}e^{-x^{\alpha}}<\infty$ always?

Comment: sorry there is a typo in the comment...I mean $e^{-x^\alpha}<\frac{1}{x^3}$ $\forall \alpha>0$

Answer (score 8):

For $x > 0$ is, using the Taylor series for the exponential function and the inequality between arithmetic and geometric mean:
$$
\begin{align}
 e^{x^2} &> 1 + x^2 + \frac {1}{2!} x^4 + \frac {1}{3!} x^6 \\
 &= \frac 14 \left( 4 + 4 x^2 + 2 x^4 + \frac 23 x^6\right) \\
 &\ge \sqrt[4]{4 \cdot 4 x^2 \cdot 2 x^4 \cdot \frac 23 x^6} \\
& > \sqrt[4]{16 x^{12}} = 2 x^3 \, ,
\end{align}
$$
which gives the slightly better estimate
$$
 e^{-x^2} < \frac{1}{2x^3} \, .
$$

Comment: the inequality involving $\sqrt[4]{}$ where come from?

Comment: @jin: That is the [inequality between arithmetic and geometric mean](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inequality_of_arithmetic_and_geometric_means#The_inequality): The arithmetic mean is $\ge$ the geometric mean.

Answer (score 3):

**Solution 1** Let $h(x)=x^3e^{-x^2}.$ Then
$$h'(x)=3x^2e^{-x^2}-2x^4e^{-x^2}=x^2e^{-x^2}[3-2x^2]$$
The maximal value for $x>0$ is attained at $x=(3/2)^{1/2}.$ Hence
$$x^3e^{-x^2}\le a:= {\sqrt{3}\over \sqrt{2}}\,{3\over 2}e^{-3/2}$$
That's a best possible constant. The function $xe^{-x}$ attains the maximum at $x=1$ and is equal $e^{-1}. $ Hence $${\sqrt{2}\over \sqrt{3}}\,{3\over 2}e^{-3/2}\le {\sqrt{3}\over \sqrt{2}}e^{-1}={\sqrt{6}\over 2e}<{1\over 2}$$ According to WolphramAlpha ${\sqrt{6}\over 2e}<0.451.$ On the other hand $0.4<a<0.41.$ So the estimate given by @Martin R is pretty close to the optimal one.

**Solution 2** For $0\le x< 1$ we have $x^3e^{-x^2}<1.$ For $x\ge 1$ there holds $x^3e^{-x^2}\le x^4e^{-x^2}.$ So it suffices to estimate $t^2e^{-t}$ for $t\ge 1.$ The maximal value is attained at $t=2$ and is equal  $4e^{-2}<1.$

Comment: This is probably the simplest and most straightforward approach.

Comment: @MartinR Thanks. I admire your proof, as it gives an efficient constant with a tricky reasoning. (+)

Comment: Thanks a lot for your proof

Answer (score 2):

Edit: Now that the question has been updated, I will remove my (no longer relevant) counterexample.

It is enough to prove for $x>0$, that $x^3<e^{x^2}$, which you can prove by differentiating $g(x)=e^{x^2}-x^3$.

$g'(x)=2xe^{x^2}-3x^2$

$g''(x)=(2+4x^2)e^{x^2}-6x$

$g'''(x)=(12x+8x^3)e^{x^2}-6$

$g''''(x)=(12+48x^2+16x^4)e^{x^2}$

Now $g^{(4)}$ is strictly positive for $x>0$, and $g^{(3)}(0)=0$, so $g^{(3)}$ is strictly positive for $x>0$. Similarly, $g''(0)=g'(0)=g(0)=0$, so we can continue this reasoning to obtain that $g$ is strictly positive for $x>0$, which yields the desired inequality.

Comment: sorry there was a typo in the inequality

Comment: I have not understood your argument...g'(x) has to be positive to ptove my statement. How can I prove this?

Comment: @jin - I have updated my solution to explain this

Comment: Thanks a lot!!!

Answer (score 0):

Let $f(x)=x^3e^{-x^2}$. We want to show that $f(x)<1$ for all $x>0$.

$f$ is maximized when $f'(x)=0$.

$$f'(x)=3x^2e^{-x^2}+x^3(-2xe^{-x^2})=x^2e^{-x^2}(3-2x^2)$$

and this is $0$ when $x=\sqrt{3/2}$.

At this max we have $f(\sqrt{3/2})=(3/2)^{3/2}e^{-3/2}=(1.5/e)^{3/2}$.  This is obviously less than 1 since $e>1.5$.

Since $f<1$ at its maximum value, it must be so for all $x>0$.